# How to reconnect to MQTT server after CONNECTIONLOST?

Tags: mqtt, raspberry-pi, python

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with SIM7600X 4G HAT for communication with Python.
I want to connect to MQTT server to receive messages via writing MQTT commands directly to the serial port of the SIM7600 (based on the manual examples).

It works fine for a while, but after a few hours it loses MQTT connection, and I can't reconnect the same way as I connected the first time.

This is my main loop:

```python
def loop():
    global isMQTTServerReady
    
    while True:
        if isMQTTServerReady:
            if ser.inWaiting():
                EVENT = ser.read(ser.inWaiting()).decode()
               
                if "+CMQTTCONNLOST" in EVENT:
                    connectToMQTT()
                    

                if "+CMQTTRXPAYLOAD" in EVENT:
                    # do something with the MQTT message
        else:
            connectToMQTT()
        time.sleep(5)
```

And this is my connect function:

```python
def connectToMQTT():
    openSerialPortIfNotOpen()
    
    ser.write("AT+CRESET")
    time.sleep(5)
    log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))
    time.sleep(1)
    
    ser.write('AT+CMQTTSTART\r\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(3)
    log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))
    
    
    ser.write('AT+CMQTTDISC=0,60\r\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(2)
    log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))
      
    ser.write('AT+CMQTTREL=0\r\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(2)
    log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))
    
    ser.write('AT+CMQTTSTOP\r\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(2)
    log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))
    startAndSubscribe()
    
def startAndSubscribe():
    global isMQTTServerReady
    isMQTTServerReady=False
    
    ser.write('AT+CMQTTSTART\r\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(3)
    log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))
    
    ser.write('AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,'+MQTT_CLIENT_NAME+'\r\n'.encode())
    time.sleep(5)
    log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))

    ser.write(MQTT_BROKER_URL+',60,1\r\n'.encode())
    
    while not isMQTTServerReady:
        connStatus = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        log (connStatus.decode())
        
        if "+CMQTTCONNECT: 0,0" in connStatus.decode():
            time.sleep(.1)
            log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))
            ser.write('AT+CMQTTSUB=0,12,1,0\r\n'.encode())
            time.sleep(2)
            log(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()))
            ser.write(MQTT_TOPIC_NAME.encode())
            time.sleep(3)
            isMQTTServerReady=True
        
        if "+CMQTTCONNLOST:" in connStatus.decode():
            connectToMQTT()
```

It works for a while, but after 1-2 hours I got into this loop (this is the log file):

```
AT+CRESET

AT+CMQTTSTART

ERROR

AT+CMQTTDISC=0,60

+CMQTTDISC: 0,11       #--> 11 means: No connection

ERROR

AT+CMQTTREL=0

+CMQTTREL: 0,19       #--> 19 means: Client is used

ERROR

AT+CMQTTSTOP

+CMQTTSTOP: 21       #--> 21 means: Client not released

ERROR

AT+CMQTTSTART

+CMQTTSTART: 23       #--> 23 means: Network is opened

ERROR

AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,"client_1"

+CMQTTACCQ: 0,19       #--> 19 means: Client is used

ERROR

AT+CMQTTCONNECT=0,"tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883",60,1

+CMQTTCONNECT: 0,13       #--> 13 means: Not supported operations

ERROR
```

And I stuck in an infinite loop of trying to reconnect, but it can never reconnect again. But if I reboot the device, it works fine again.

What is wrong with this? I thought that if I lose connection, I should:

- disconnect client, -release client, -stop mqtt, -start mqtt, -acquire client, -connect to mqtt and then subscibe to topic, as it is in the [Sim 7600X Manual](https://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/6/65/SIM7500_SIM7600_Series_MQTT_ATC_V1.01.pdf)

Comment: It's quite possible that there is something weird with your hardware. I am familiar with the SIM800 which can get into a state where it wont accept AT commands at all until it is reset. I've never worked with your device but it is very possible that it's a similar type of thing. For debugging, if it's possible add some breakpoints and watch where the execution goes. Other things you can do is perhaps divide and conquer. Add the bare minimum in functionality and slowly increase to isolate where the problem is.

Comment: Other things you can do is add debug messages that print to let you know exactly where your program goes. This is useful if you don't have a debugger and can't set breakpoints. But be careful not to send debug messages to the SIM7600. It will be very confused if you do that. :)

Comment: I am fighting the same issues - did you resolve your reconnect issues? How? Thanks Scott

Comment: you may endup having to control the power to the module and do a hard reboot that way. Also, see if you have the latest firmware for the module.